# Difference between “unhappy with/by the new tax policy”

Tags: prepositions, difference

Actually, I'm learning English speaking and I'm not good at it.

During learning English, I've got a question.

How do you feel those two sentences?

> 1. I knew people would be unhappy with the new tax policy
> 2. I knew people would be unhappy by the new tax policy

I've heard native speaker said 1.

but I guess, when it comes to non-native speaker, saying 1. is difficult.

is 2.sentence little bit strict feeling??

Comment: In 2 you can either change **by** to **with** (which would make it the same as 1), or add one word: "I knew people would be **made** unhappy by the new tax policy."

Comment: Thank you so much. I've realized what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

2 is incorrect.   You could say "unhappy with" or "unhappy about". To "be unhappy by" has no meaning.
You might say "I knew people would be *made* unhappy by the new tax policy.", but that's different.

Comment: I really appreciate you. "by" could be used to passive form sentence.